# How to customize URL to get desired result with requests

Tags: python, url, web-scraping, python-requests

I am trying to extract the data from the [website](https://www2.daad.de/deutschland/studienangebote/international-programmes/en/result/?q=&fos=&cert=&admReq=&scholarshipLC=&scholarshipSC=&degree%5B%5D=&langDeAvailable=&langEnAvailable=&lang%5B%5D=&cit%5B%5D=&tyi%5B%5D=&ins%5B%5D=&dur%5B%5D=&prep_subj%5B%5D=&prep_degree%5B%5D=&sort=4&subjects%5B%5D=&limit=10&offset=&display=list). So far I am able to do extract the data but I need to make it more customized. The URL that I need to manipulate is [this](https://www2.daad.de/deutschland/studienangebote/international-programmes/en/result/?q=&fos=&cert=&admReq=&scholarshipLC=&scholarshipSC=&degree%5B%5D=&langDeAvailable=&langEnAvailable=&lang%5B%5D=&cit%5B%5D=&tyi%5B%5D=&ins%5B%5D=&dur%5B%5D=&prep_subj%5B%5D=&prep_degree%5B%5D=&sort=4&subjects%5B%5D=&limit=10&offset=&display=list):

This is how its changing, the number for D from 1-8.
[image]

1 is for bachelor, 2 is for master, 3 for PhD and so on...
[image]

I need to add an extra column in my data frame based on that.

This is how my code looks:

```
import requests
import pandas as pd

r = requests.get("https://www2.daad.de/deutschland/studienangebote/international-programmes/api/solr/en/search.json?cert=&admReq=&scholarshipLC=&scholarshipSC=&fos=&langDeAvailable=&langEnAvailable=&sort=4&q=&limit=2099&offset=&display=list&isSep=").json()

data = ["link", "courseName", "academy",
        "city", "languages", "programmeDuration", "beginning", "subject", "tuitionFees", "image", "dateString"]
d = []
for item in r["courses"]:
    d.append([item[x] for x in data])

df = pd.DataFrame(*[d], columns=data)

df.to_csv("data.csv", index=False)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since there's info about the course type in the payload, create a mapping for the `courseType` value and then edit the column in the `df`.

Note: I couldn't figure out what `56` maps to, so I went for `N/A` but this might be a `Prep course / language course`.

One way of doing this would be:

```
import requests
import pandas as pd

r = requests.get("https://www2.daad.de/deutschland/studienangebote/international-programmes/api/solr/en/search.json?cert=&admReq=&scholarshipLC=&scholarshipSC=&fos=&langDeAvailable=&langEnAvailable=&sort=4&q=&limit=2099&offset=&display=list&isSep=").json()

course_type_mapping = {
    "1": "Bachelor's degree",
    "2": "Master's degree",
    "3": "PhD/Doctorate",
    "4": "Cross-faculty graduate and research school",
    "5": "Prep course",
    "6": "Language course",
    "7": "Short course",
    "8": "Study online"
}

data = [
    "link", "courseName", "courseType", "academy", "city", "languages",
    "programmeDuration", "beginning", "subject", "tuitionFees", "image",
    "dateString",
]
d = []
for item in r["courses"]:
    d.append([item[x] for x in data])

df = pd.DataFrame(*[d], columns=data)
df['courseType'] = df['courseType'].apply(lambda x: course_type_mapping.get(str(x), "N/A"))
df.to_csv("data.csv", index=False)
```

Output a column with course types:

[image]

Comment: Thanks and the solution is perfect. But can you explain what do you mean by payload and from where I can see it?

Comment: By payload I mean what you get back from the request you make. You can take a look at it with `print(r['courses']`.